# discord.py Error: Task was destroyed but it is pending! task: <Task pending coro=<Client._run_event() running at

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('------')
    print('Logged in as ' + client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    print('Made by k0rndawg')
    print('ready when you are, dude')
    print('------')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!watch"):
        itemlink = message.content.split(" ")[1]
        if 'www.ebay.com' in itemlink:
            #await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Correct link')
            number_of_watchers = message.content.split(" ")[2]
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Sending {} Watchers to {}".format(number_of_watchers, itemlink ))
            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)

        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Incorrect link')



        testing = Generator(itemlink)
        for x in range(0, int(number_of_watchers)):
            testing.test()

            #await asyncio.sleep(10)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Successfully Sent {} Watchers to {}".format(number_of_watchers, itemlink))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Hi there, could someone please explain the following error to me? I'm using requests for the class im calling, and I read that that could be a problem, but it just looks like the async is having trouble with the for loop?
The error is the following:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Client._run_event() running at
```

I saw that there were other posts with questions about this error, but none as unique to this situation, so im wondering what the fix would be?

Comment: I don't think the error is caused by the code you've posted. I'm not sure what `Generator(itemlink)` is doing (since it's your custom class) but since it's called testing and doesn't impact the output in any way I've removed it and the code runs fine

Comment: Would you expect `for x in range(0, int(number_of_watchers)): testing.test()` to take a long time (a few seconds)?  If you block the event loop for too long the bot will stop working.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes it does take around a minute or so depending on how many watchers the person selects. How would I circumvent the block of the event loop?

Comment: You need to make it a asynchronous event which can be run with await to make it non-blocking

Comment: @Tim could you give me an example of that? I tried but i don't think i was doing it correctly

Comment: I don't have much experience with async in python so am not sure about the best way to use it with your code (mainly used async in other languages) but when doing async sutff in python in the past this article was useful https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/.